# Send Form Data Through JQuery AJAX / javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have a form like this;

```
<form action="out.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="a" />
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="b" />
    <input type="hidden" name="c" value="c" />
    <input type="hidden" name="d" value="d" />
    <input type="hidden" name="e"  maxlength="60" value="e" />
    <input type="hidden" name="f" value="f" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create & Send">
</form>
```

this form can not be seen by users. They just see a submit button like "Create Label & Send To Customer" .
But they need to input Customer's eMail Address. So i have a js code the submit button trigger it. And it asks the email address.
The JS code:

```
$('#dialog_prompt').click(function(){
    $.prompt("What is customer's email?","",
    function(value){
        $.msg("So, you like '"+value+"'?");
    },
    function(){
        $.msg("You clicked cancel!");
    });
});
```

So my problem is;
when the user submit the button and input the customer's email and hit the ok, JS must send the values from the form & email address to the "out.php".

So how can I send form data via JS?

Comment: use ajax for sending Post data

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<form action="out.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="em" value="" class="customeremail" />
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="a" />
<input type="hidden" name="b" value="b" />
<input type="hidden" name="c" value="c" />
<input type="hidden" name="d" value="d" />
<input type="hidden" name="e"  maxlength="60" value="e" />
<input type="hidden" name="f" value="f" />
<input type="submit" value="Create & Send">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#dialog_prompt').click(function(){
    $.prompt("What is customer's email?","",
    function(value){
        $('form .customeremail').val(value);
        $('form').ajaxSubmit();
    },
    function(){
        $.msg("You clicked cancel!");
    });
});
```

Comment: when i submit like this, nothing happens. i clicked the button and put the mail address and wait and wait. but nothing happened.

Comment: By the way I have 3 forms in my page. And this form has "sendemail" id.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the details using AJAX.

```
$('#dialog_prompt').click(function(){
                $.prompt("What is customer's email?","",
                function(value){        
                    $.msg("So, you like '"+value+"'?");

                    $.ajax({
                    url: "out.php",   // url to which details are send
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),   // pass form details
                    } ).done (function(data) {      // on success

                  });

                },
                function(){
                    $.msg("You clicked cancel!");
                });
            });
```

Now you can access the values passed through AJAX in *out.php* page using `$_POST`.

Note : The `serialize()` method creates a URL encoded text string by serializing form values.

Comment: Hello, how can i grab the email address? out.php waits $_POST['custemail']

Comment: By the way I have 3 forms in my page. And this form has "sendemail" id.